# Problemas al iniciar sesion

Tags: php, html

tengo una consulta, intento evitar el ingreso al sistema por medio de un inicio de sesión, el cual se funciona correctamente, el problema es que no me restringe el acceso por medio de la url y permite el ingreso normal, lo cual no debería pasar.

Si alguno de uds tiene alguna idea o puede ver el error que tengo en mi validación de usuario lo agradezco porque he revisado y me parece que el código está bien.

```html
<?php
  session_start();
  require '../login/funcs/conexion.php';
  include '../login/funcs/funcs.php';
  
  if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
    header("Location: ../../index.php");
  }
  else
  {
  
  $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
  
  $sql = "SELECT id, usuario FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Forma Producciones</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Menu/styles.css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../../Iconos/logo.gif">
  <script src="../../Menu/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../../Menu/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script Language="JavaScript">
if(history.forward(1)){
history.replace(history.forward(1));
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
<link href="../../Css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../../Iconos/logo.gif">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.Estilo9 {color: #660000;
 font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="formulario" method="get" onSubmit="return validar()">
<table width="130%" height="80%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tabla">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="height: 185px; margin-top: 5px;"><img src="../../Imagenes/Logo.png"></td>
  </tr>
<div>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="Menu"></td>
  </tr>
</div>
  

  <tr>
    <td width="176" height="362" align="center" valign="top"  class="Menu">
      <?php include("../../Menu/Menu.html"); ?>    </td>
    <td width="2000" align="center" class="centro"><iframe name="pagina" id="pagina" width="100%" height="180%" frameborder="0" src="../Index/Index.php"></iframe></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="pie">Copyright © 2020 - 2022, <span class="Estilo2">Forma Producciones Audiovisuales</span>, Todos los derechos reservados</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estoy muy seguro que antes de hacer tu header(Location...) hay una salida de información (puede ser un error, warning, etc) que impide que el header se realice correctamente.

Comment: Aparte de lo mencionado por @FernandoTorres, header() solo envía un encabezado al navegador, pero PHP continúa en ejecución, agrega `exit;` debajo de la redirección para evitar que se siga enviando contenido.